# Why was conn held by low-ranking officers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

**PREFACE:** As there appears to be some confusion about this, note that "conn" in Star Trek is not necessarily defined the same way as in present-day nautical terms. In particular, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flight_control_officer) says:

> The flight control officer, also known as conn officer, or simply conn/helm, was the crewmember on a Federation starship assigned the duty of piloting the vessel. This position combined the roles of the navigator and helmsman used previously. The term "conn" was also used to refer to the flight control station itself.

Thus, "conn" on Star Trek is *not* the person in charge of the bridge, *not* the person who gives commands or who determines the course, it's the person who enters the coordinates to travel to or who rotates the vessel and activates thrusters.

---

In some of the Star Trek series, most notably in TNG, the conn officer (the person steering the ship) was often a rather low-ranking crewmember. In particular, the [list](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flight_control_officer#List_of_flight_control_officers) included total newbies (Wesley Crusher), crewmembers who would occasionally also do other things (Ro Laren), and an overall large number of ensigns, some Lieutenants Junior Grade, and a few full Lieutenants. While watching TNG, this gave me the impression that plenty of officers with basic training are fit to be assigned to the conn station without any specific piloting skills.

The same sometimes happened on DS9's Defiant, when it was not the main cast filling in as a conn.

Now, this seems to be somewhat in conflict with how the position of the conn was presented in the other series, sometimes also on TNG:

- First, in the [TNG episode "Booby Trap"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Booby_Trap_(episode)), a delicate maneuver has to be executed… and Picard replaces the conn officer to do that. Not only does this show Picard is another officer who can casually use the conn console, presumably without any special preparation, but it is an example where the conn officer (who should presumably be *the* specialist for flight control on the bridge) is not deemed capable enough for the tricky part of the task.
- Likewise, in [*Star Trek: Insurrection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection), Riker uses the "manual control column" himself once a complex maneuver has to be performed.
- In series where the permanent conn officer(s) belong to the main cast (TOS, VOY, ENT), they are not just "some crewmembers who usually man the conn" (as it was sometimes the case with LaForge and Worf in TNG's 1st season). Instead, actually quite a big deal is made about at least Sulu and Paris specifically being excellent navigators/pilots.
- And lastly, it also seems somewhat logical that "taking the conn" of a large starship might require some additional training. Entering target coordinates for a travel at warp speed may be unproblematic, and we do not know exactly to what extent the computer helps the pilot pilot the ship. Yet, at least when we look at the degree of manual control during the aforementioned special maneuvers, it becomes evident that the conn officer would have to have extensive experience with piloting the particular ship class. While it is conceivable these maneuvers are not normally needed and thus most crewmembers do not need that training, it is also doubtful whether the captain or first officer of all people would be the ones to have that training.

Therefore:

#### Is there any information on why especially TNG conveyed an "everyone can do conn" impression?

Is this maybe based on some real precedent from military ships that was (mindlessly or not) taken over for TNG?

Comment: The job of "flight control officer" is a pretty low-ranking one. You don't really make any decisions about the direction or speed of travel and your role can largely be replaced by the computer.

Comment: Note, the conning officer is _not_ the pilot/helmsman/navigator. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conn_(nautical), which describes the actual nautical basis for this. Essentially, the conning officer is responsible for managing the ship while boring things are happening, and the captain (though they may not be a captain in rank) or another responsible higher ranking officer takes over when the situation warrants someone with a higher degree of responsibility or experience. See for example the couple of episodes of Voyager where Harry Kim is in command of the bridge on the night shift.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: In the context of Star Trek, you're wrong. cf. e.g. [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flight_control_officer): "The flight control officer, also known as conn officer, or simply conn/helm, was the crewmember on a Federation starship assigned the duty of piloting the vessel. This position combined the roles of the navigator and helmsman used previously. The term 'conn' was also used to refer to the flight control station itself."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111786/discussion-on-question-by-o-r-mapper-why-was-conn-held-by-low-ranking-officers).

Comment: I'm somewhat confused here.  You wrote , 'Thus, "conn" on Star Trek is not the person in charge of the bridge, not the person who gives commands or who determines the course'.  "Star Trek" includes more than TNG.  In TOS, the term "conn" was definitely used for the person in charge of the bridge.  When said person left the bridge, he designated the person to take that position (see, for example, "The Tholian Web", "That Which Survives", etc. etc.  Even in TNG itself, "The Skin Of Evil" (Picard: "I'm going to beam down. Lieutenant Worf, you have the conn."), contradicting your assertion.

Comment: @Basya: True, in TOS, the term "conn" still seemed to have a different meaning (more in line with how the term is used in present-day navies), and it seems early TNG episodes may sometimes have used it this way before the definition as the flight control officer prevalent throughout the 24th century series was nailed down.

Comment: Regardless of who was the *conn* officer, Paris was the *con* officer.

Answer (score 42):

The conn officer is essentially the Star Trek version of the helmsman/navigator positions on a modern ship. While the navigation officer tends to be Second or a Third Mate (or military equivalent), the actual helm is often manned by enlisted personnel during normal open water sailing. So if you're combining the positions, it makes sense for it to be a senior noncom or junior officer, especially as the computer handles most of the duties anyway.

As for one of the senior officers taking over the helm in certain circumstances, this isn't entirely unprecedented either. For instance, on large modern ships, the helm controls are usually duplicated on the bridge wings and when docking or departing the commanding officer often has hands-on control themself to execute the fine manoeuvres.

Comment: Right. It seems that "everyone can do conn" is true under *normal* circumstances, but when special maneuvers are required then someone with more experience may step in. It's sort of like the real military where nearly anyone in uniform can load and fire a rifle, but only a few are qualified snipers. If you just need the thing across the room dead you don't need to call in a sniper.

Comment: Is that true? The captain of a large modern ship would trust himself over a qualified able seaman to execute fine docking maneuvers? I would have thought the captain of a carrier would be more used to driving a jet fighter than a large ship, but I don't know anything about it. Were you in the navy?

Comment: I would've thought the CO would have a million administrative tasks to do as they entered port. Unless piloting the ship in is what they do to *avoid* those tasks...

Comment: @user14111, the able seaman at the helm follows the orders of the officer of the deck. The officer decides something like "come to 123, all ahead full" and the helmsman executes those orders. The US Navy requires that carrier captains are/were aviators, a holdover from the early days when they feared that the battleship captains would smother the new aviation personnel.

Comment: @user14111, watch a the video of a (civilian) captain controlling his own ship (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WhTwtCxCo8), a captain giving his first officer control as part of her training (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYiuQUKwEH0), another captain docking her ship (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHpjoFuFHsU), a cruise ship staff captain handling the ship (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djc1WN1YmpY), and so on.

Comment: @o.m., but US carrier captains, while starting out as aviators, are required to qualify as regular line officers and have ship command on other vessels before someone hands over the keys to a CVN. As a notable example, Captain Brett Crozier of the *Roosevelt* first served as executive officer of the *Reagan*, then commanded the amphibious command ship USS *Blue Ridge*, and then was finally assigned to the *Roosevelt* as captain.

Comment: @Cadence, entering port, like landing an aircraft, is one of the more hazardous things ships do on a routine basis. A captain who *wasn't* on the bridge during that time, even if they aren't at the helm directly, would almost certainly find themselves as an ex-captain after not very long.

Comment: @RobertColumbia "when special maneuvers are required then someone with more experience may step in." or someone whose job is to take responsibility if the ship crashes. Totalling a starship isn't something that it is fair to put on an ensign's service record.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: If the commanding officer is not actually better trained to steer the ship than the ensign, it doesn't make sense for them to take control. There are plenty of situations where a higher-ranking person takes responsibility for successful execution of a task, but delegates the actual task to a specialist who has the actual skill to perform the task. This comes back to my question, though - *does* a commanding officer have that training? Or *does* a "random" ensign have that training? Actually, *both* strike me as somewhat unlikely.

Comment: The "Steering the ship during docking" bit seems like one of those hangovers from old maritime tradition. It's not just that the Captain is higher ranked, they're also absolutely responsible for the lives of everyone on board, and the safety of the vessel. See "The captain goes down with his ship", or, more pragmatically, "is the last person off when it's sinking". They are rules and traditions more designed to highlight that responsibility, and ensure there are personal consequences if you screw up, rather than be practical.

Comment: This is discussion conflating different levels of "skill" and "training". Staying with naval ships, knowing how to make the ship move in a particular direction at a particular speed is a fairly low level task - it isn't fundamentally different from knowing where the gas and brake pedals and the steering wheel are on a car. On the other hand, deciding *what* speed and direction you need to go in is a different ball game (and that is why you can't learn to drive a car safely in normal traffic conditions in half an hour, of course!)

Comment: ... Also, in peace time the captain of a large ship is *not* likely to be the person in charge of entering port and docking. The ship will take a pilot on board, whose job is to know the local details of geography and tides, the capabilities of the local tug boats, etc. In effect the pilot gives orders to the captain, who can ignore them at his/her own risk, but usually would be foolhardy to do so!

Comment: @alephzero, that's assuming a port has a pilot. This may be true for most large ports around the world, but it's certainly not the case for all of them. And given that I provided links to videos specifically showing captains at the controls while docking, I fail to see why you'd claim it was unlikely.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, why would you assume the captain doesn't have the basic training to control the vessel? If they've started off in small craft, odds are they were the ones at the controls. You don't suddenly forget things with higher ranks.

Comment: It's also worth bearing in mind that different captains/enlisted personnel might have differing levels of previous training or want different levels of hands-on control. Expecting one protocol for all situations is unreasonable, and knowing when it's wise to change things up is basically the Captain's job.

Comment: @JoeBloggs, a good example of that is the TNG episode "Booby Trap". At the end Picard takes the helm because the plan is one he and LaForge came up with, he approved, and if something goes wrong it will be his responsbility.

Comment: The thing about "Booby Trap" is that it wasn't a situation where the helm was operating as normal.  The entire ship had been shut down save for two thrusters and nothing else.

No one had "training" on this so the captain doing it made as much sense as any other crewer perhaps save Data.  

With just two thrusters controlled by two buttons, it was essentially playing "Flappy Bird" with a Galaxy Class Starship.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Now I'm imagining the Captain calling up the Admiral, "Uh, Dad... I locked the keys in the CVN. Can you bring the spare set down?"

Answer (score 28):

In the merchant marine and in the navy, the person who steers the ship and holds the steering wheel is usually low ranking.

In European nautical tradition, in the age of sail, ships were steered by someone holding the tiller, a long lever connected to the rudder, in a room in the stern castle of the ship, which had a very poor view. An officer on deck who could see the position of the ship would give them orders when changing course was necessary.

Otherwise, it was necessary for the person holding the tiller to hold it steady as winds and waves changed, and to make certain the masts didn't shake violently and drop crewmen off.

About the year AD 1700, steering wheels were invented. Then the person holding the steering wheel was up on the deck of the ship and had a view. But masts and sails often blocked the view, and the person holding the helm had to keep on holding it. The officer in change could move around on the deck and even climb partway up a mast, to get a better view, and there were usually lookouts high in the masts to shout down to the deck what they saw.

Thus the officers continued to tell the man holding the steering wheel when to change course and how to change course.

Owen Chase, first mate of the whaling ship *Essex* wrote how a sperm whale charged at the ship and he told the boy at the wheel to turn the ship in a vain attempt to avoid being rammed. The boy at the wheel was named Thomas Nickerson, the youngest member of the crew, and he had turned 15 during the voyage.

The lookouts in the crow's nest of RMS *Titanic* spotted an iceberg ahead, and telephoned down to the bridge. The officer in command ordered quartermaster Robert Hitchens to turn the wheel to try to avoid the iceberg.

I once saw a recruiting ad for the US Navy depicting a teenage sailor at the steering wheel of an atomic submarine. Nobody can see where an atomic submarine is going while it is underwater for weeks and months at a time, so they need sonar and good navigation to know when to change course.

In the nautical tradition of our civilization, low ranking persons do the actual steering, obeying the instructions of the officers in charge. See [my answer on the history SE site here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43617/how-did-the-helmsman-know-what-he-was-sailing-towards-with-a-big-mast-in-his-fac/43637#43637).

With the speeds of *Star Trek* starships, interstellar voyages should often take days of heading in the same direction. So all that a helmsman might do during a single watch might be to periodically check to make sure they are on course and wait around for something to happen to give them a reason to change course. So that doesn't seem like a job for senior officers to me.

So *Star Trek* shows which depict helmsman as a job for low ranking crew members seem to be in line with Earth's nautical history and with the logic of interstellar travel. *Star Trek* shows like TOS which depict the job of helmsman as an important position filled by officers seem to be the odd ones.

Comment: Also military ships, e.g. in both world wars, often had the actual wheel below the deck where it was well armoured and the officer of the watch shouted commands from the bridge through a pipe. That way if the bridge, which is always much more likely to get hit, was damaged, that or another officer could continue giving orders from a backup location. If the wheel was on the bridge, it could easily get jammed in a hit and then backup location wouldn't help.

Comment: When I sailed on a brigantine, steering was the worst job of the watch. It required total concentration to keep it from swerving, and I don't blame the officers for passing it down to the lowest person on the totem pole.

Comment: "About 1700 steering wheels were invented." Presumably you mean "About 1700, steering wheels were invented." Without the comma, it means that the number of steering wheels that were invented was 1700.

Comment: Weren’t Sulu and Chekhov (and unnamed red jumpsuits) the most usual helmsmen in TOS? They were a lieutenant and an ensign, the lowest officer ranks, even if they were also in the main cast.

Comment: @Acccumulation Ah, the comma... the difference between inviting your elder to dinner ("Let's eat, grandma!") and having your elder as dinner ("Let's eat grandma!").

Comment: @ThePhoton lieutenant is O3, a mid-ranking officer.

Comment: @OrangeDog Do we ever see a LtJG in Trek? If the Federation doesn’t have that rank then Lt is just the next thing above ensign.

Comment: @ThePhoton [yes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_lieutenants_junior_grade)

Answer (score 20):

Helmsman != pilot != navigator != conn.

There's a navigator (often Pavel Chekov in TOS,) there's a helmsman (often Hikaru Sulu in TOS,) and then there's "the conn."

Whoever has "the conn" is in temporary command of the ship, and can give orders as needed to the helmsman, the navigator, or whoever else needs told what to do to maintain the course and task given by the captain.

Conn has to decide when things are normal and make decisions to keep things running, or to request the Captain or other command officer to take over when the situation is no longer normal (that is, not what it was when the commanding officer turned over the conn to a lower officer.)

---

In the shows, the Captain often "takes the conn" and sits in the Captain's seat on the bridge to oversee routine operation.

When the Captain or another line officer on bridge duty at the conn has to leave the bridge, then that officer can appoint someone to "hold the fort" until the officer returns.  The appointed person "has the conn" and monitors the normal operations and gives commands as allowed by the position and the authority it confers.  The person holding "conn" sits in the Captain's seat and gives orders.

The person at the conn **could** give orders to set course for the Andromeda galaxy and expect to be obeyed - though someone is certain to check with a higher officer or the Captain if the mission at hand has nothing to do with Andromeda.

In the episodes mentioned in the question, the Captain or other officer wasn't just acting as conn, but rather as pilot or helmsman.

Those are rare exceptions.  Cases where the responsibility is more important than the ability - or even more rare, where the commanding officer is actually better able to do the pilot's job than the pilot is.

Lower rank officers can hold "conn" because it is a temporary authority granted by a higher ranking officer with the expectation that the lower ranking officer will recall the higher ranking officer (or appropriate higher authority) if conditions change.

Comment: In Star Trek, the "conn officer" *is* the helmsman, pilot, and navigator. See my edit to the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper:  The conn officer may **also** be a pilot, navigstor, or helmsman.  The conn officer usually sits in the command seat, but may stay at the normally assigned station.

Comment: The memory alpha quote conflicts with what is seen on screen in nearly every episode.

Comment: Please elaborate. What *is* seen on screen in nearly every episode with respect to who is called "conn officer"/what station is called "conn", in your opinion?

Comment: Watch damn near any episode.  Captain gets up from the command seat, says "So and so, you have the conn."  In TOS, "So and so" gets up and goes to sit in the captains chair.  TNG, "So and so" may move to the command seat or not.  In both cases, the officer with the conn is now temporarily in command.  Often "So and so" was the navigator or the helmsman, which makes hash of your "conn is helmsman" argument.

Comment: Helm is **already** helm, no need to pass it on.  Conn is passing command authority.  "You have the conn" changes the on duty helmsman or navigator from "follow orders and carry out your normally asdigned duties" to "give orders and carry out your normally assigned duties."

Comment: That usage of "conn" seems to be restricted to TOS. From TNG onwards (which I'm mainly asking about. cf. my question), "conn" is synonymous with helm/navigation. Virtually every mention of "conn" from TNG onwards that I can find in the transcripts on Chakoteya contradicts your claims. Some examples: 1) TNG "Preemptive Strike": Picard tells Ro Laren: "I'd like you ad the conn, Lieutenant." In the next scene, Picard and Ro enter the bridge, Picard takes command, while Ro sits down at the flight control station ("conn station"). 2) TNG "Timespace": Picard reports: "There are three Romulans ...

Comment: And what does Picard say whdn he leaves the bridge?  "Mr. Data, you have the conn."  Data is **already** at the navigation/helm station.

Comment: ...  (...) One at conn." By that, he's referring to the Romulan sitting at the flight control station that we can briefly glimpse. 3) TNG "Yesterday's Enterprise": Castillo says "Fredericks, take the conn.", whereupon a crewman goes to sit down at the flight control station, while Castillo remains on the bridge, in command.

Comment: Can you point out a single TNG episode where that sentence is uttered, please? The common phrase on TNG and later series appears to be "you have the **bridge**", *not* "you have the conn".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The Skin Of Evil" (Picard: "I'm going to beam down. Lieutenant Worf, you have the conn.")

Answer (score 13):

Star Trek is largely based on naval traditions - ranks onboard ship match, the voyage of discovery trope is pretty much the series premise.

Maritime traditions are set out to emphasize personal responsibility for the captain of the vessel. It's not sufficient to blame the idiot ensign for messing up the navigation, it's your job as Captain to ensure they did it right, and were trained correctly. You have both complete power, and complete responsibility over the vessel, and everyone on board.

Therefore, it's your job, as Captain, to know how to steer the ship, and how the ship handles. You don't get away with being untrained in this, because it informs all the rest of the decisions you make. What size space you can fit through. Can you cut off an opponent, bring your weapons round before they can turn?

It also means you take the conn at times that it's likely to kill everyone on board. Your ship, your responsibility for their lives, your job to steer them through it.

Random, but somewhat senior people taking the helm fits with this. It's also your job to protect the vessel even if you're killed or incapacitated. Cross training your crew is very common, even on small boats. This means letting people who are being trained try steering, navigation etc under calm, sensible circumstances.

It's also essential for those in your crew to progress up the ranks. It would be very reasonable for them to have a requirement to "Have spent x hours flying x ship" in order to be promoted, and, again, as Captain, it's your responsibility to push them, and train them to command vessels of their own.

Comment: "Therefore, it's your job, as Captain, to know how to steer the ship, and how the ship handles. You don't get away with being untrained in this, because it informs all the rest of the decisions you make." - this seems to be a crucial point that I wasn't quite aware of. It does make me wonder, though, why the captain would ask e.g. the chief engineer for advice on engineering matters rather than taking over control over engineering themselves, as well. The same arguments seem to apply there; knowing the technology and its status in and out informs all the rest of the decisions.

Comment: I think you'd expect the captain to know, say, the power of the engines, how to control the ship when they break, and a bunch about their theoretical workings and possible  risks (i.e, what happens when the ship is on fire and you go to warp). It's a different discipline. The age of sail analogy is that ships had carpenters on board. If you get a big hole in the side, the captain should have an idea of when it is too big, how to sail to slow the water coming in, and when the ship needs to be abandoned, but the carpenter should be able to fix it

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, the captain would almost certainly be expected to know enough to understand what the engineer is telling him, *maybe* to be able to do those duties in an emergency, but the engineers *live and breath* that stuff. They have *way* more experience than the captain. You could as well ask why a general practitioner will still ask a cardiologist for advice about a heart problem. (con't...)

Comment: (...con't) Picard taking over in Booby Trap may even be more Rule of Drama than realistic, though in that case the stakes were much higher than usual. OTOH, the difference in experience levels in that instance may not be nearly as pronounced as e.g. Picard vs. LaForge when it comes to engineering matters. (Also, that is an instance where sheer nerve may be as important as technical experience. Crusher may be a genius, but he's still just a kid.)

Comment: @Matthew: Fully agree concerning "engineers live and breath that stuff". And I'd expect the very same thing to be true for flight control. The captain will very well know how to generally steer the ship, what thrusters are available, etc. But I wouldn't expect the Captain to have the same "feeling" for the precise effect each thruster at each setting will have that a long-time helmsman would. Good point about sheer nerve, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, and the key point there is "*long time*". For exactly that reason, I wouldn't expect Janeway to take over from Paris, but Crusher has only been doing it for about a year or so. In the specific instance of Booby Trap, it's entirely possible *Picard* has the greater experience. (Plus, *thrusters* don't get used that often outside of e.g. docking maneuvers. We're not sure how much experience Crusher has with them. Conversely, Riker has enough experience to perform a manual rejoining to the saucer section in Farpoint; it's reasonable to assume Picard has at least as much.)